# Debugging the application in .net

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a solution in .Net(C#) which have more than 40 project files.While I am running the application,it throws some exception some where. The problem here is I need to put breakpoint and debug through the application.

Is there anyway to findout the where the exception is thrown.Like inheriting the Exception class.

Comment: Usually, it breaks on the exception. Is there a bunch of try / swallow going on, and do you have the correct .NET version being debugged in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

Under the **Debug** menu in Visual Studio, select **Exceptions...** and check **Thrown** under **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**. This will break when *any* exception is thrown as opposed to just unhandled exceptions.