# Debugging the application in .net

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

whenever an exception occurs,by default it creates an New object of exception class.
Is there a way to findout the how many exception objects are created in the application.

Or Is there anyway to put the breakpoint in the construtor of the exception class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging the application in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230088/debugging-the-application-in-net)

Comment: I get the feeling there's a better approach.  What overall problem are you trying to solve?  What would be the benefit of knowing how many instances of Exception (and inherited classes) are instantiated on the heap?  (Keep in mind that some exceptions are instantiated even if they're not used.  OutOfMemory, StackOverflow, etc. are instantiated and kept in memory in case they're needed, since when they occur the resources might not exist to instantiate them.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how many exceptions per second are happening in your app using VS profiling. Just launch a sampling profiler session from visual studio. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647791.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfhcywhs.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx